# How to reach and read GUI data from graphics memory

Tags: linux, hardware, video, gui

I want to connect an e-ink display to a single board linux machine, PINE64. 
E-ink display should be used as primary monitor, i.e. GUI should be shown on that.
Since there is no direct method to connect an e-ink display to usual graphics ports such as HDMI, VGA, DVI, I would like to know whether or not it is possible to reach graphics memory in linux and read GUI data, parse it for e-ink display and send data over SPI or I²C to display controller.
If it is possible on which distrubution?

There is one method that I found so far. Take screenshots periadically and save it as image, parse image and send it to display controller over SPI. But I think this methode is not efficient.

Or is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at implementing the Remote Framebuffer Protocol RFB, described in [RFC 6143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143). This is used by [VNC](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/howitworks.html) servers and clients which are common on many systems. On Linux the package may be called `tigervnc-server` for the server `Xvnc` (or a script front-end `vncserver`), and package `tigervnc` for the usual X11 client `vncviewer`, but there are different versions.

The protocol is described [here (pdf)](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/rfbproto.pdf). It is intended to be lightweight and easy for a client to implement. The advantage is that only changed parts of the screen need to be redrawn.